# Ink! ink_env::debug_println! does not work if message is payable

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node

Adding `#[ink(payable)]` to a `#[ink(message)]` prevents `ink_env::debug_println!` messages to be logged in console when executing the smart contract call.

Any additional config needed in this case to have `ink_env::debug_println!` in console?

Comment: Are you runining node with -dev --tmp -lruntime::contracts=debug flags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug messages are only emitted during a dry run (`query`), not during the actual transaction (`tx`)([Source](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/issues/13#issuecomment-1020798193)).

When you're calling the contract, first query it. Then perform your transaction if there are no error messages.

e.g.

```
public async transaction(signer: Signer, method: string, args: any[]): Promise<Partial<TransactionResponse>> {

    // View any debug in substrate logs and catch any errors here
    const queryBeforeTx = await await this.contract.query[method](this.account.address, {}, ...args);

    // Then run your transaction
    const extrinsic = this.contract.tx[method]({}, ...args);
```

Comment: That's true for polkadotjs-UI. But you can print to the console of the substrate node & it works with tx as well

Comment: Personally, when I submit a tx from the polkadot apps interface, I don't get any ink! debug on the substrate node. When I submit a query, I do get ink! debug on the substrate node.

Comment: This is when I'm running substrate with log flags `-lerror,runtime::contracts=debug`

Comment: just tested with polkadotjs & you are right. I got log on query but not on tx