# How to get a detailed error for a Solang-compiled contract with polkadot-js?

Tags: polkadot-js, smart-contract, solidity, solang

I'm currently using substrate (version 4) with the contrat-pallet. I deploy contract in wasm, compiled from solidity (thanks to solang compiler) and sometimes, when executing a method of the smart contract, I encounter an error. When I take a look on the polkadotjs apps I have the following message :

[image]

But this message is not so explicit and doesn't help to figure out how to solve the problem.

Furthermore, the output of the polkadotjs api when I run this code :

```
contract.tx.method({ storageDepositLimit, gasLimit })
.signAndSend(pair, result => {
    if (result.status.isFinalized) {
        return result.toHuman()
    }
})
```

is not really more explicit :

```
{
  dispatchError: { Module: { index: '9', error: '0x0b000000' } },
  dispatchInfo: { weight: '80,051,097,517', class: 'Normal', paysFee: 'Yes' },
  events: [
    { phase: [Object], event: [Object], topics: [] },
    { phase: [Object], event: [Object], topics: [] }
  ],
  internalError: undefined,
  status: {
    Finalized: '0x2e6cfa203369435efd17144525e265508e801865baf7d8f8989883a553ddf4b8'
  }
}
```

By experience, this kind of errors can occurs when a "require" from the solidity smart contract doesn't pass. But I don't have any details and I don't find how to get the require output message from the smart contract.

Is there any way to get more detail on error to know what is going on ? To get the message from the "require" in the solidity smart contract ? To know from what part it came from ?

Thanks !

Comment: Before you do a transaction (`tx`) [perform a `query`](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2359/380) to get errors and debug messages from the substrate contracts node.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ink! ink\_env::debug\_println! does not work if message is payable](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/ink-ink-envdebug-println-does-not-work-if-message-is-payable)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @forgesto. I tried to query the contract to get errors but the `debugMessage` is empty while it should contains the message from the `require` of my solidity smart contract. Do you think this issue came from the solang compiler ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Are you doing a cross contract call and can you share contract code? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67769831/1178971) is what the `index` and `error` relate to.

Comment: To get the error in a meaningful format, do something like [this](https://github.com/patractlabs/redspot/blob/b2755736f0583d8f634a71ffe1e442a03b109549/packages/redspot-patract/src/buildTx.ts#L46-L63)

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not yet possible to view the error message directly in the `polkadot.js` UI. To see your error message from the `require` statement you need to:

- Compile `solang` yourself from the latest master branch and use that. We added this feature recently and it is not yet released (it will be in V 0.2).
- Make sure your node is configured to display the debug buffer, [as described here](https://ink.substrate.io/faq#how-do-i-print-something-to-the-console-from-the-runtime).